# How do I get a value from this localStorage array to create a new var?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Here is the localStorage entry I want to use:

**Key**: file

**Value**: [{"id":"usethis","somethingelse":"otherstuff"}]

I want to create a var from id in the Value array so I can make an `if` that says:

```
var idvalue = ??? (...this is what I need help retrieving...)

if (idvalue == "usethis") { ...do some stuff... } else { ...do something else... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
//read the string value from localStorage
var string = localStorage.getItem('file');
//check if the local storage value exists
if (string) {
    //if exists then parse the string back to a array object and assign the first item in the array to a variable item
    var file = JSON.parse(string),
        item = file[0];
    //check whether item exists and its id is usethis
    if (item && item.id == "usethis") {} else {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks but there seems to e a syntax error in there somewhere. Can't paste the example without an error on line with second if.

Comment: @user1452893 there was a `=` missing

Comment: Thanks so much for going the extra mile for me! That example is very helpful and helps me learn.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40085/discussion-between-user1452893-and-arun-p-johny)

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 Local Storage only handles string key/value pairs.  To save your JSON object in Local Storage you will have to stringify it when you save it, and parse the string when you read it back. It is all explained very well in the following StackOverflow question [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage).

Comment: Thanks looks like there are a lot af competing examples in there. I just want one that works.